# Understanding what ajax is doing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, azure

As part of my coursework I have to build a web app that connects to a database, all hosted on azure and implementing the REST api.
I've set up a MySQLdatabase and am now trying to work through the example code my lecturer gave out in order to tweak it to my current project. Only I am having some trouble following it. The desired structure is that index.html has a button, when this is pressed a call to NameWebService uses ajax to connect to a php file which then deals with the database connection and data collection.
Yet nothing is being return from the database (and being unable to debug php from webmatrix I'm not 100% sure the connection is even being established).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NameWebService.js

```
var year;
var gender;

function SetValues() {
    year = document.getElementById('Year').value;
    gender = document.getElementById('Gender').value;
}

function getNames(year, gender)
{
    //alert(year + '\n' + gender);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Name',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'table='+year,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Data is:\n'+data)
           createNamesTable(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(jqXHR + '\n' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function createNamesTable(Names)
{
    var strResult = '<div class="col-md-12">' + 
                    '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">' +
                    '<thead>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<th>Rank</th>' +
                    '<th>Name</th>' +
                    '<th>Change Since Last Year</th>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</thead>' +
                    '<tbody>';
    $.each(Names, function (Rank, Name){                        
        strResult += "<tr><td>" + Name.Rank + "</td><td> " + Name.Name + "</td><td>" + Name.Change + "</td>";
    });
    strResult += "</tbody></table>";
    $("#allNames").html(strResult);
}
```

calls to PHP and consequently database, takes back the data and creates a table from it.

NameRestService.php

```
<?php    
    require "RestService.php";
    require "Name.php";

class NameRestService extends RestService 
{
  private $Domain = 'domain';
  private $User = 'username';
  private $Password = 'password';
  private $Database = 'database';
  private $Names;

  public function __construct() 
  {
    parent::__construct("Name");
  }

  public function performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    $this->initialiseData($_GET['table']);
    echo json_encode($this->Names);
  }

  private function initialiseData($year)
  {
      $this->Names = [new Name("100000","Test","-23124324"),new Name("100001","Testtwo","-24")];
  }
}
?>
```

And extension of the RestService the provided specific functionality we want. despite explicitly only setting Names to be one entry, this always returns empty. I'm also not sure the database is connecting properly.

RestService.php

```
<?php

class RestService 
{
  private $supportedMethods;
  private $apiStringToMatch;

  public function __construct($apiStringToMatch) 
  {
    $this->supportedMethods = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE";
    $this->apiStringToMatch = $apiStringToMatch;
  }

  public function handleRawRequest($_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST) 
  {
    $url = $this->getFullUrl($_SERVER);
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if (isset($_GET['q']))
    {
        $parameters = explode("/", $_GET['q']);
        if (strlen($this->apiStringToMatch) > 0 && count($parameters) > 0)
        {
            if (strcmp($this->apiStringToMatch, $parameters[0]) != 0)
            {
                $this->notImplementedResponse();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $parameters = array();
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])) 
    {
      $accept = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'];
    }
    else 
    {
      $accept = "";
    }
    $this->handleRequest($url, $method, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept);
  }

  protected function getFullUrl($_SERVER) 
  {
    $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$location;
  }

  public function handleRequest($url, $method, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    switch($method) 
    {
      case 'GET':
        $this->performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept);
        break;
      default:
        $this->notImplementedResponse();
    }
  }

  protected function notImplementedResponse() 
  {
    // 501 Not Implemented 
    header('Allow: ' . $this->supportedMethods, true, 501);
  }


  protected function methodNotAllowedResponse() 
  {
    // 405 (Method Not Allowed)
    header('Allow: ' . $this->supportedMethods, true, 405);
  }

  protected function notFoundResponse()
  {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
  }

  protected function noContentResponse()
  {
    header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
  }

  // Override the following methods to provide the appropriate functionality

  public function performGet($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
  {
    $this->methodNotAllowedResponse();
  }
}
?>
```

Base class for the Rest api, lays out basic foundations. I can't tell if the ajax request is coming to here or to the NameRestService...

Name.php

```
<?php
class Name
{
    public $Rank;
    public $Name;
    public $Change;

    public function __construct($rank, $name, $change)
    {
        $this->Rank = $rank;
        $this->Name = $name;
        $this->Change = $change;
    }

    public function GetRank()
    {
        return $this->Rank;
    }

    public function GetName()
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }

    public function GetChange()
    {
        return $this->Change;
    }
}
?>
```

Base object for our data is being stored as.

---

**EDIT:**

I've been speaking with some peers and we have started to figure out what needs to be done. The site is using the web.config to reroute requests to an api.php which is then initializing the rest of the php.

I have also cut back a lot of the non vital code for this stage and updated the above to match. web config and api.php are as such:

api.php

```
<?php
    require "NameRestService.php";

$service = new NameRestService();
$service->handleRawRequest($_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST);
?>
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
         <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
         <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php"
              verb="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" 
              modules="FastCgiModule" 
              scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe"
              resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
       </handlers>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="api.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is that now I am getting an internal service error whenever I try to access the PHP functions.

Comment: that's a lot of code for us to attempt to debug

Comment: Sorry
I wasn't sure what was needed so I put enough so people should be able to understand most of what's going on.

Comment: Learn how to use browser dev tools to inspect requests (data sent/returned, headers, status etc...lots to see). Not sure what route is being used ....`echo json_encode($_REQUEST);`

Comment: @charlietfl,  I've been trying to use the F12 tools in Chrome.
Is there a way I can get the php to out put there as it goes about its thing?

Comment: look into Xdebug and a simple script add-on is FirePhp.  IDE's with integrated servers let you set php breakpoints and step through the code execution

Answer (score 1):

To monitor and debug AJAX calls, use your browser's developer tools (Press F12). You'll then see a Network tab, where you can watch all traffic to the server, including parameters and the response data. In some browsers you there is an XHR sub-tab, that filters for only AJAX requests (helpful if you have a lot of images, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Name',
```

be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/NameRestService.php',
```

Comment: I had it like that for a while but I kept getting "internal service error"